# I am unable to improve the (MAProcess) time series model

Tags: distributions, time-series, random-process

I am a time series novice and have been learning the art/trade from examples while being governed by the [NIST handbook (ch.6, sec.4)](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc4.htm).

My question is regarding:

- How to improve the estimated time series process?  Currently the ACF of the residuals of my estimated process is not entirely Normally-distributed noise.
- Is this a time series problem at all?  Should I use a distribution fit instead?

I have a dataset (`x`) fluctuating between discrete values 1 - 5.  The raw data and the "differenced" data are shown.  The CSV data is **available via this [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/iyL1tB07).**  It is comma-separated numeric data.

[image]

I converted the data to `TemporalData` and performed a `UnitRootTest`.

```
xtd = TemporalData[Differences[#], {Length[Differences[#]]}] & /@ x;

UnitRootTest[xtd[[1]], 1, "HypothesisTestData", 
 SignificanceLevel -> .05]
```

`(*The null hypothesis that the model of order 1 without a constant offset and no deterministic trend contains a unit root is rejected at the 5. percent level based on the Dickey-Fuller F test.*)`

The differenced data is stationary, as indicated by the small p-value from the UnitRootTest and the rejection of the $H_0$.

I used the `CorrelationFunction` to visualize the autocorrelation of the resulting time series.  There is one spike (negative) at the first lag and then a rapid decline to within the 95% confidence interval.

```
conflevel = 0.95;
samplesize = xtd[[1]]["PathLengths"][[1]];
{minconf, maxconf} = 
 Quantile[NormalDistribution[], {(1 - conflevel)/2, 
   1 - (1 - conflevel)/2}]/Sqrt[samplesize]

ListPlot[N@CorrelationFunction[xtd[[1]]["PathStates"], {100}], 
 PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1.1}}, Filling -> Axis,
 GridLines -> {None, {-0.05, 0.05}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.015]}]
```

[image: width:100]

Based on my limited knowledge, it would appear that I may need an `MAProcess` with one parameter since I have a spike at lag 1 along with a quick diminishing of the ACF to within the confidence interval (See [Box-Jenkins identification](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc446.htm) from the NIST Handbook).

I estimate the `MAProcess` parameters:

```
est = EstimatedProcess[xtd[[1]]["PathStates"], MAProcess[{a}, v]]
```

`(*MAProcess[{-1.}, 0.78754]*)`

Then I compute the residuals of the estimated process with respect to the original data hoping that the residuals would be normally distributed noise (their ACF would be within their 95% confidence interval in their ACF plot)... **but the residuals do not stay within the confidence intervals!**

So I assume that my estimate is not a good fit.

```
residuals = 
  Rest[xtd["PathStates"] - 
    KalmanFilter[est, xtd[[1]]]["PathStates"]];

clev = 0.95;
samplesize = 
  TemporalData[residuals, {Length@ residuals}]["PathLengths"][[1]];
{minconf, maxconf} = 
 Quantile[NormalDistribution[], {(1 - clev)/2, 
   1 - (1 - clev)/2}]/Sqrt[samplesize]

DiscretePlot[CorrelationFunction[residuals, n], {n, 0, 10}, 
 ExtentSize -> 1/2, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1.1}}, PlotStyle -> Black,
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, FrameLabel -> {"lag", "ACF"}, 
 GridLines -> {None, {-0.05, 0.05}}]
```

- What parameters should I add to my `MAProcess`?  I have tried an ARMAProcess as suggested by `TimeSeriesModelFit` but that has a worse residual ACF.
- Is this a timeseries problem?

[image]

Comment: Try considering the pACF and an ARMA(p,q) process.

Comment: @corey979 How do I specify that? Is it `EstimatedProcess[xtd[[1]]["PathStates"], ARMAProcess[{a},{b}, v]]`  I think I did but to not much improvement.